# How to move iPad Safari bookmarks to Safari on my Mac?

Tags: ipad, safari, bookmarks

I want to move my safari bookmarks from my iPad to my MacBook computer exactly as they are on my iPad. Not the other direction. Not merge. I would like exactly the same contents and order intact. Happy to lose/overwrite the bookmarks file on the computer.